# Are elements of ArrayList in Java reallocated in the memory when new ones are added If the size of the ArrayList has been passed to the constructor?

Tags: java, list, memory, arraylist, memory-management

I am trying to write the method that efficiently wraps each element in the `List` passed to this method and returns the created `ArrayList` with wrapped elements.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The size(), isEmpty(), get(), set(), iterator(), and listIterator() operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

Do I understand it right that If I create an `ArrayList` and pass the initial capacity to the constructor, the elements in `ArrayList` won't be reallocated in memory when new ones are added?

Example:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<RequestToExternalSource<T>> wrapExternalSources(List<ExternalSource<T>> externalSources, BiConsumer<Integer, T> publishResult) {
    ArrayList<RequestToExternalSource<T>> requests = new ArrayList<>(externalSources.size());

    ListIterator<ExternalSource<T>> externalSourcesIterator = externalSources.listIterator();
    int index = 0;

    while (externalSourcesIterator.hasNext()) {
        requests.add(new RequestToExternalSource<>(
                index++,
                externalSourcesIterator.next(),
                publishResult));
    }
    return requests;
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you don't exceed the capacity.

Comment: The storage is reallocated any time the list needs to extend the size of the internal array. Since you pre-allocated the array to exactly the size needed, *your* code will not cause a reallocation. However, if the caller adds another element to the returned array, a reallocation will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this, we can look directly at the source code of `ArrayList#add`.  We first see the following method:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    modCount++;
    add(e, elementData, size);
    return true;
}
```

The method above calls the following `private`, overloaded `add` method:

```
private void add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) {
    if (s == elementData.length)
        elementData = grow();
    elementData[s] = e;
    size = s + 1;
}
```

We can see that `elementData` (the `Object[]` that holds the data) will only grow when `s` (the size parameter, equal to `ArrayList#size` in our case) equals the length of the data array.  For this reason, `elementData` is not *grown* even if we add `n` elements to an `ArrayList` initialized with a capacity of `n`, which is good!

> Do I understand it right that If I create an ArrayList and pass the initial capacity to the constructor, the elements in ArrayList won't be reallocated in memory when new ones are added?

For these reasons, yes, you're correct, until you add more elements than the capacity specified.